# Installing Gnome 3.10 along Ubuntu 13.10 (mouse cursor missing)

Tags: gnome

I installed, Gnome 3.10 along Ubuntu 13.10, however after installation. My mouse pointer is not showed on my desktop. How can I back and show the mouse pointer? I was not able to navigate properly because of this.

Comment: How is Ubuntu installed on the machine, are you using a Virtual Machine?

Comment: It's a dual boot, alongside windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

that always worked for me

Comment: `modinfo psmouse [...] description:    PS/2 mouse driver` do you still use a [PS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector) mouse?

Comment: yep i use two mouses 1 is usb and the other ps/2

Answer (score 1):

Try to issue this command in a terminal:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Seems a sort of conflict between Gnome 3.10 and the rest of the world...